# How to send a string array in HttpClient post method in Angular 14?

Tags: angular

I try to send a string array with HttpClient post method to my backend.

```
getAnnouncementsByIds(ids: string[]): Observable<Announcement[]> {
  return this.http.post<Announcement[]>(`${environment.serverUrl}${this.urlGetAnnouncementsByIds}`, ids);
}
```

Current error is: Http Status 400 with message "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `[Ljava.lang.String;` from Integer value (token `JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT`);

I tried different things to make it work:

- add the number array as stringified value to HttpParams
- add a header with "Content-Type": "application/json"

i cant find a solution how to send an array as body in an Http Post request.

Can someone help me? Im sure it should be pretty easy.

Comment: You should definitely include your Java Code of the endpoint you are trying to make a request to. Can you also include the actual payload you are sending from your browser's network tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a object like this:

```
export interface IdList{
 ids: string[]
}
```

First option:

```
getAnnouncementsByIds(ids: string[]): Observable<Announcement[]> {
  const rq = {ids = ids} as IdList
  return this.http.post<Announcement[]>(`${environment.serverUrl}${this.urlGetAnnouncementsByIds}`, rq);
}
```

Second option:

```
getAnnouncementsByIds(ids: IdList): Observable<Announcement[]> {
  return this.http.post<Announcement[]>(`${environment.serverUrl}${this.urlGetAnnouncementsByIds}`, ids);
}
```

Comment: Your sugesstions maked me able to find the Problem. After i implemented your first option i debugged the backend (spring boot). ids did not came as ['1','2','3'] instead it was ['1,2,3']. With this knowledge i maked it work. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the array with an object

```
getAnnouncementsByIds(ids: string[]): Observable<Announcement[]> {
  // ids -> { ids }
  return this.http.post<Announcement[]>(`${environment.serverUrl}${this.urlGetAnnouncementsByIds}`, { ids });
}
```

So your backend will get this value

```
{
  ids: [...]
}
```

Comment: when i wrap the array with an object like suggestet i still get an http 400 but the error message changed:
"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `[Ljava.lang.String;` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`);

Comment: @mdyingstar Maybe it's not Angular's fault then? I use wrapped array in Angular, send data to Nest.js/Node.js and it works fine